# how to remove fieldname in pipeline stage in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("123456"), 
    "likers" : [
        {
            "userId" : ObjectId("111111")
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like to the result to be

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("123456"), 
    "likers" : [ ObjectId("111111")]
}
```

I cant figure out the next stage operation.

Is there an operation that I don't have to use javascript?

thanks so much

```
db.getCollection("post").aggregate([
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "reaction",
            let: { id: "$_id" },
            pipeline: [
              {
                $match: {
                  $expr: { $eq: ["$postId", "$$id"] }
                }
              },
              {
                $project: { userId: 1, _id: 0 }
              },

            ],
            as: "likers"
          }
        }
      ])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this :

```
 db.getCollection("post").aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "reaction",
            let: { id: "$_id" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: { $eq: ["$postId", "$$id"] }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $project: { userId: 1, _id: 0 }
                },

            ],
            as: "likers"
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            "likers": {
                $map:
                {
                    input: "$likers",
                    as: "each",
                    in: '$$each.userId'
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Ref :** [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) , [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html)